# How can I find the mean of each value in a sequence across the whole dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, sequence

[image: Snapshot of DataFrame]

`score` is the score received on each delivery and `runs` are the cumulative of the score. `sequence` is the the 6 delivery sequence of `length/type` each over. I am trying to find the average score of each delivery  within a sequence across the whole dataset and the average runs for a sequence.

using this code I have got something like this but the problem is that each `length/type` does not repeat when it is grouped, so the cumulative of the averages, `runs` is not the correct 6 ball total:

```
df_seq=df_seq.reset_index()
df_sq = df_seq.groupby(['sequence', 'length/type']).agg({'score':'mean'})
df_sq['runs']=df_sq.groupby(['sequence'])['score'].cumsum()
df_sq
```

Here is a the original dataframe `to_dict` with index reset:

```
{'Event_name': {0: 'fulham',
  1: 'fulham',
  2: 'fulham',
  3: 'fulham',
  4: 'fulham',
  5: 'fulham',
  6: 'fulham',
  7: 'fulham',
  8: 'fulham',
  9: 'fulham',
  10: 'fulham',
  11: 'fulham'},
 'Batfast_id': {0: 'bfs00200002',
  1: 'bfs00200002',
  2: 'bfs00200002',
  3: 'bfs00200002',
  4: 'bfs00200002',
  5: 'bfs00200002',
  6: 'bfs00200002',
  7: 'bfs00200002',
  8: 'bfs00200002',
  9: 'bfs00200002',
  10: 'bfs00200002',
  11: 'bfs00200002'},
 'Session_no': {0: 1,
  1: 1,
  2: 1,
  3: 1,
  4: 1,
  5: 1,
  6: 1,
  7: 1,
  8: 1,
  9: 1,
  10: 1,
  11: 1},
 'Overs': {0: 0,
  1: 0,
  2: 0,
  3: 0,
  4: 0,
  5: 0,
  6: 1,
  7: 1,
  8: 1,
  9: 1,
  10: 1,
  11: 1},
 'Deliveries_faced': {0: 0,
  1: 1,
  2: 2,
  3: 3,
  4: 4,
  5: 5,
  6: 6,
  7: 7,
  8: 8,
  9: 9,
  10: 10,
  11: 11},
 'score': {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 6.0,
  5: 4.0,
  6: 0.0,
  7: 0.0,
  8: 0.0,
  9: 0.0,
  10: 0.0,
  11: 0.0},
 'runs': {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 6.0,
  5: 10.0,
  6: 10.0,
  7: 10.0,
  8: 10.0,
  9: 10.0,
  10: 10.0,
  11: 10.0},
 'delivery_type': {0: 'Extra Slow Leg Spin',
  1: 'Extra Slow Leg Spin',
  2: 'Slow Straight',
  3: 'Extra Slow Off Spin',
  4: 'Extra Slow Leg Spin',
  5: 'Extra Slow Leg Spin',
  6: 'Extra Slow Off Spin',
  7: 'Extra Slow Off Spin',
  8: 'Slow Straight',
  9: 'Extra Slow Leg Spin',
  10: 'Extra Slow Off Spin',
  11: 'Extra Slow Off Spin'},
 'length': {0: 'Yorker',
  1: 'Yorker',
  2: 'Yorker',
  3: 'Yorker',
  4: 'Yorker',
  5: 'Yorker',
  6: 'Yorker',
  7: 'Yorker',
  8: 'Yorker',
  9: 'Yorker',
  10: 'Yorker',
  11: 'Yorker'},
 'length/type': {0: 'ES_LS_Y',
  1: 'ES_LS_Y',
  2: 'S_S_Y',
  3: 'ES_OS_Y',
  4: 'ES_LS_Y',
  5: 'ES_LS_Y',
  6: 'ES_OS_Y',
  7: 'ES_OS_Y',
  8: 'S_S_Y',
  9: 'ES_LS_Y',
  10: 'ES_OS_Y',
  11: 'ES_OS_Y'},
 'sequence': {0: 'ES_LS_Y,ES_LS_Y,S_S_Y,ES_OS_Y,ES_LS_Y,ES_LS_Y',
  1: 'ES_LS_Y,ES_LS_Y,S_S_Y,ES_OS_Y,ES_LS_Y,ES_LS_Y',
  2: 'ES_LS_Y,ES_LS_Y,S_S_Y,ES_OS_Y,ES_LS_Y,ES_LS_Y',
  3: 'ES_LS_Y,ES_LS_Y,S_S_Y,ES_OS_Y,ES_LS_Y,ES_LS_Y',
  4: 'ES_LS_Y,ES_LS_Y,S_S_Y,ES_OS_Y,ES_LS_Y,ES_LS_Y',
  5: 'ES_LS_Y,ES_LS_Y,S_S_Y,ES_OS_Y,ES_LS_Y,ES_LS_Y',
  6: 'ES_OS_Y,ES_OS_Y,S_S_Y,ES_LS_Y,ES_OS_Y,ES_OS_Y',
  7: 'ES_OS_Y,ES_OS_Y,S_S_Y,ES_LS_Y,ES_OS_Y,ES_OS_Y',
  8: 'ES_OS_Y,ES_OS_Y,S_S_Y,ES_LS_Y,ES_OS_Y,ES_OS_Y',
  9: 'ES_OS_Y,ES_OS_Y,S_S_Y,ES_LS_Y,ES_OS_Y,ES_OS_Y',
  10: 'ES_OS_Y,ES_OS_Y,S_S_Y,ES_LS_Y,ES_OS_Y,ES_OS_Y',
  11: 'ES_OS_Y,ES_OS_Y,S_S_Y,ES_LS_Y,ES_OS_Y,ES_OS_Y'}}
```

Below is a good example because there are only 2 overs of this sequence in the data set:
[image: Example sequence]

The result I'm trying to get from this sequence is an average of the score for each delivery and the cumulative average runs as follows:

```
                                                           score runs
sequence                                      length/type       
ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F ES_LS_F     0.0   0.0
                                                ES_LS_F     2.0   2.0
                                                ES_LS_F     0.0   2.0
                                                ES_LS_F     0.0   2.0
                                                ES_LS_F     2.0   4.0
                                                ES_LS_F     0.0   4.0
```

ie the `score` for the first delivery would be `(0+0)/2 = 0`. the second would be `(0+4)/2 = 2` and so on. `runs` are the cumulative of this.

example `to_dict`

```
{'Event_name': {475442: 'gps',
  475443: 'gps',
  475444: 'gps',
  475445: 'gps',
  475446: 'gps',
  475447: 'gps',
  523148: 'gps',
  523149: 'gps',
  523150: 'gps',
  523151: 'gps',
  523152: 'gps',
  523153: 'gps'},
 'Batfast_id': {475442: 'bfs5301209',
  475443: 'bfs5301209',
  475444: 'bfs5301209',
  475445: 'bfs5301209',
  475446: 'bfs5301209',
  475447: 'bfs5301209',
  523148: 'bfs5302591',
  523149: 'bfs5302591',
  523150: 'bfs5302591',
  523151: 'bfs5302591',
  523152: 'bfs5302591',
  523153: 'bfs5302591'},
 'Session_no': {475442: 1,
  475443: 1,
  475444: 1,
  475445: 1,
  475446: 1,
  475447: 1,
  523148: 1,
  523149: 1,
  523150: 1,
  523151: 1,
  523152: 1,
  523153: 1},
 'Overs': {475442: 4,
  475443: 4,
  475444: 4,
  475445: 4,
  475446: 4,
  475447: 4,
  523148: 2,
  523149: 2,
  523150: 2,
  523151: 2,
  523152: 2,
  523153: 2},
 'Deliveries_faced': {475442: 24,
  475443: 25,
  475444: 26,
  475445: 27,
  475446: 28,
  475447: 29,
  523148: 12,
  523149: 13,
  523150: 14,
  523151: 15,
  523152: 16,
  523153: 17},
 'score': {475442: 0.0,
  475443: 0.0,
  475444: 0.0,
  475445: 0.0,
  475446: 4.0,
  475447: 0.0,
  523148: 0.0,
  523149: 4.0,
  523150: 0.0,
  523151: 0.0,
  523152: 0.0,
  523153: 0.0},
 'runs': {475442: 22.0,
  475443: 22.0,
  475444: 22.0,
  475445: 22.0,
  475446: 26.0,
  475447: 26.0,
  523148: 16.0,
  523149: 20.0,
  523150: 20.0,
  523151: 20.0,
  523152: 20.0,
  523153: 20.0},
 'delivery_type': {475442: 'Extra Slow Leg Spin',
  475443: 'Extra Slow Leg Spin',
  475444: 'Extra Slow Leg Spin',
  475445: 'Extra Slow Leg Spin',
  475446: 'Extra Slow Leg Spin',
  475447: 'Extra Slow Leg Spin',
  523148: 'Extra Slow Leg Spin',
  523149: 'Extra Slow Leg Spin',
  523150: 'Extra Slow Leg Spin',
  523151: 'Extra Slow Leg Spin',
  523152: 'Extra Slow Leg Spin',
  523153: 'Extra Slow Leg Spin'},
 'length': {475442: 'Full',
  475443: 'Full',
  475444: 'Full',
  475445: 'Full',
  475446: 'Full',
  475447: 'Full',
  523148: 'Full',
  523149: 'Full',
  523150: 'Full',
  523151: 'Full',
  523152: 'Full',
  523153: 'Full'},
 'length/type': {475442: 'ES_LS_F',
  475443: 'ES_LS_F',
  475444: 'ES_LS_F',
  475445: 'ES_LS_F',
  475446: 'ES_LS_F',
  475447: 'ES_LS_F',
  523148: 'ES_LS_F',
  523149: 'ES_LS_F',
  523150: 'ES_LS_F',
  523151: 'ES_LS_F',
  523152: 'ES_LS_F',
  523153: 'ES_LS_F'},
 'sequence': {475442: 'ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F',
  475443: 'ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F',
  475444: 'ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F',
  475445: 'ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F',
  475446: 'ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F',
  475447: 'ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F',
  523148: 'ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F',
  523149: 'ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F',
  523150: 'ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F',
  523151: 'ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F',
  523152: 'ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F',
  523153: 'ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F,ES_LS_F'}}
```

`sequence` was made using the following code:

```
df_reg['sequence'] = (df_reg.groupby(["Event_name", "Batfast_id", "Session_no", "Overs"])["length/type"]
                       .apply(lambda x: ",".join(x)).loc[lambda x: x.str.count(",") == 5]

                   )
```

If I was able to uniquely number each delivery in the sequence I would be able to do it.

Comment: So it means expected output is from data bellow `to_dict` data? So not match with 'to_dict' sample?

Comment: `to_dict` is just a sample of data. Below is an example of different data. would you like the to_dict of the example?

Comment: problem is if pass to_dict then is possible change it manually for perfectly sample. then is necessary add expected output fro mthis sample, not with some another data. Because cannot run data from picture.

Comment: thanks, so is possible add expected ouput? Because not understand how possible from one `4` value get `2`, also next `2` (guess mismach)

Comment: Advice - remove unnecessary columns, e.g. by `df_seq[['sequence', 'length/type', 'score']]` and then working with this sample should be simplier.

Comment: @jezrael I have put an updated `to_dict` for the example that is now correct.

Comment: @jezrael please use the updated `to_dict` not the one that was initially there. There were rows missing in that one

Comment: thanks. Is correct `e the score for the first delivery would be (0+0)/2 = 0. the second would be (0+4)/2 = 2` ? My problem is not understand it.

Comment: so the 1st delivery of the 1st over is `0`. The 1st delivery of the 2nd over is `0`. Therefore the average of the 1st delivery in this sequence is 0. the 2nd delivery of the 2nd over is `0`. The 2nd delivery of the 2nd over is `4`. Therefore the average of the 2nd delivery in this sequence is '2' etc. `runs` are just the cumulative of this

Comment: I have also added how the `sequence` was made. If I was able to uniquely number each delivery in the sequence then I would be able to do it